# Does this line give us the root node of the Binary Search Tree? BST currentNode = this;

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand this code which deletes a value from a Binary Search Tree. I am confused by the line that says BST currentNode = this; I am assuming that after this line currentNode will be equal to the root node of the BST that the remove method was invoked on. I am unsure, however, if this is the case. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could tell me if my interpretation of BST currentNode = this; is correct or if I am missing something.
*I did not attach the entire code as it is very long, but this should be enough because my confusion is only with the line that says BST currentNode = this;
Thanks everyone!

```
public BST remove(int value, BST parent) {
     BST currentNode = this;
     while(currentNode != null) {
        parentNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.left;
     }
}
```

Comment: `this` is definitely "**a** root of **a** BST" on which `remove` has been invoked, in the sense that 1) _every_ node of a BST is the root of a BST, and 2) `this` always refers to the object on which an instance method has been invoked.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was very helpful. Just to clarify, the remove method can be called on any node of the BST correct?
Also, if we called remove on a node who's value was 10 (remove(10);) would `currentNode` be equal to this node who's value is 10?

Comment: In theory, the `remove` method you've shown could be called on _any_ node in BST.  And if you happened to invoke it on a node whose value was 10, `this` would be that node, and consequently `BST currentNode = this;` would also be that node, whose value is 10.